# Is there a way to estimate or calculate the expected P99 of a sum of distributions?

Tags: distributions, quantiles, aggregation

Suppose I have an event X whose latency I cannot measure directly, but X consists of a bunch of sub-events X_0, X_1, X_2, ..., X_n whose latency I can measure individually only in isolation.

Intuitively, adding the P99 latency of each of the X_i's to compute the P99 of X seems incorrect, because the P99 events for each of the X_i's are unlikely to all happen at the same time.

**Is there a standard and/or mathematically correct way to calculate the expected P99 latency of X, given the measured latency distributions of all the components?**

I will try to clarify my terms and question with a concrete example:

- Let X = the total amount of time spent on database queries as part of handling a specific API call.
- Let X_i = the total amount of time spent on the i_th database query.

Suppose I can measure the latency of individual database queries against a new database, and I can do so multiple times.

Further suppose that it is not practical to measure the total time spent on all queries in a single experiment.

I'd like to estimate or calculate a distribution for X based on all the X_i's, and then find the 99th percentile of that distribution.

Comment: Please tell us what you mean by "the expected P99 latency" of an "event."  The former has no commonly understood meaning in statistics and the latter is overloaded.

Comment: @whuber Apologies about the imprecise language. I'll update the question to try to bring more clarity.

Comment: @whuber I added an example to the question, but please let me know if it's still insufficiently clear.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no good way to estimate a 99th percentile of a sum from the percentiles of the components.

E.g.: Suppose that $X=Y+Z$, where both $Y$ and $Z$ are both binary variables with a 2% chance of being 1 minute and a 98% chance of being 1 second. Then the 99th percentile of $X$ could be:

- 2 minutes, e.g. if $Y$ and $Z$ are perfectly correlated, or
- 1 minute + 1 second, e.g. if $Y$ and $Z$ are uncorrelated.

Without information about the relationships between the component variables, the best you can do is give bounds for the percentile calculations.

Comment: Two clarifications: 1) I'm fine with assuming independence (no correlation) of the component variables. 2) I do not just have the percentiles of the components; I have the full empirical distributions including all the samples from experiments.

Comment: Under an assumption of independence, you can list all the empirical possibilities for $X+Y$ and compute the percentile directly, but I can’t think of a situation with latencies where independence is a sensible assumption.

Comment: That's a little strange, Matt, because independence in this context only refers to how the probabilities of pairs of queries are related.  The default model for any series of queries sufficiently spaced out over time would be that the response times are independent.  The question appears to come down to "how do you estimate the 99th percentile of a distribution from a sample of it."

Comment: But @whuber, the summands are not sufficiently spaced out in time — they are latencies for parts of a single API call.

Comment: I'm not saying you're wrong, but I read the description differently, because it characterizes the $X_i$ as "individual database queries."